# Python's partition() in C#?

Tags: c#, string, split

In Python, you can get the substring before, and after a string. An example being...

```
myString = "Hello, World!".partition(", ")
print(myString[0], myString[2]) # Index 0 is the substring before ", ", and 2 being the index after ", ".
print(myString)
```

The code above should output

```
Hello World!
['Hello', ', ', 'World!']
```

Is there any function I can use in C# that allows for this same type of action?

Comment: Though there is a little difference between string.Split in C# and parition() in python, I think the link answers OP's question. Closing this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic example using [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1):

```
void Main()
{
    string myString = "Hello, World!";

    var x = myString.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (var s in x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);       
    }
}
```

Probably better to use `","` (without the space) as a delimiter and [`Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netcore-3.1) results

Comment: This works for me, and also thanks for mentioning `Trim()`. This makes another thing I'm doing in my project much easier.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method built into the .NET standard. You can easily recreate it in C#.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition), this is what `partition` is supposed to do:

> Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing the string itself, followed by two empty strings.

We can use `IndexOf` and `Substring` to implement this in C#.

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static (string, string, string) Partition(this string str, string sep) {
        int index = str.IndexOf(sep); // find the index
        if (index >= 0) { // if found, get the substrings
            return (str.Substring(0, index), sep, str.Substring(index + sep.Length));
        } else {
            return (str, "", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = "Hello, World".Partition(", ");
Console.WriteLine(result.Item1); // Hello
Console.WriteLine(result.Item3); // World
```